# Automate repair of wireless connection on XP

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp

I suspect that there is a problem somewhere in my Dell Precision laptop, running XP Pro, that causes the wireless internet connection to be lost after about a half-hour of connection time.  The wireless router is fine, as another laptop runs without problems.

To restore my connection, I can right click on the toolbar's wireless icon, and choose repair.  However, sometimes this fails to resolve the problem, so I now open "Network Connections" right click on the wireless connection and select "disable".  And then right click again and choose "enable".  This always seems to work.

I would like to automate this process so that running a program/script/etc. on my desktop would take those actions for me.  It is tiresome clicking through the same steps over and over.  (Given that solution, I'd probably write a program to check the connection every two minutes and automatically call repair when needed.)

**Is there some way to do the disable/enable steps from a script/program/etc. ?**

I program in C#, but have been unable to find commands to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860673/programatically-disable-enable-network-interface) for this, which points to ToggleNIC [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/154712/). The last one provides a link where you can download v1.0 which works for Windows XP.

From the included readme.txt file:

> ToggleNic is a command line applications used to easily enable or disable a network connection.
>
> Usage: `ToggleNic [connection_name] [enable|disable]`
>
> If you do not specify enable or disable, the network connection will
>   be toggled (enabled if it is disabled, or disabled if it is enabled).
>   If you specify enable or disable, no change is made if the connection
>   is already in the desired state.
>
> Examples:
>
> `ToggleNic "Local Area Connection"`
>
> `ToggleNic "Local Area Connection 2" enable`
>
> `ToggleNic "Wireless Connection" disable`

Comment: Ah, what a relief.  Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does just releasing and renewing the IP address work? You could make a pretty simple batch file to do that.

```
@echo off
ipconfig -release
ipconfig -renew
```